# How to create Postgresql user without any trace of password in logs?

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I have a question about creating new Postgresql database user in C# application.
If I create user like this in psql:

```
create role foo with login;   \password foo
```

this encrypts password on client side, so no plainText is in the logs.
Guys on IRC community forum recommended that I look for something like PQencryptPasswordConn() in driver that I am using, in this case Npgsql, but I can't seem to find anything like that.

Has anybody got any idea how to create user in the same safe way as with psql?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using md5 password "encryption", you can easily do this yourself as long as you can find a c# library which computes md5 hashes as hex.  The encrypted password is simply `'md5' . md5_hex(password . username)`, where `.` is string concatenation operator.  Once you have that, you would simply do something like:

```
create role foo with login password 'md5258f951d4d9d3ea3854f265195f63dda'
```

<s>I don't think npgsql supports using scram authentication at all, so there should be no need to set a scram-encrypted password using npgsql.</s> It does support using scram to log in, but it seems to be undocumented and does not seem to support changing the password on the client side.

Comment: _"I don't think npgsql supports using scram authentication"_ it does support it since 3.2.7 [1](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1530) [2](http://www.roji.org/postgresql-10-features)

Comment: But doesn't this mean that the postgresql will hash this password itself one more time?

Comment: @niks No, if the supplied string is the right length and starts with 'md5' it is accepted as being already hashed, and won't be hashed again before storage.

Comment: @jjannes I suppose you have no way of knowing how should properly formatted SCRAM 'string' look for database to accept it as "normal" so it does not hash it again?

Comment: @JGH  I see.  Is it documented someplace?  npgsql.org doesn't seem to mention it, and I don't see any user documentation inside github.  Casually looking through the commit, I don't see anything that help change the password from the client.

Comment: @niks It would look like this "SCRAM-SHA-256$4096:6ilYXFpjK7dHgTt16BGX2w==$8pFtMOLCWRIL5K1Sq5uyUoSM3ao4W9Cr1MoFvH1alHM=:276ojgLOIZY7rvJvoE2McwJ9xgjY1sESyGXnBLE0bo0=".  I can construct strings which would avoid getting rehashed by using that as a template, but I don't know how to make ones that would actually work to allow one to log in, so just avoiding rehashing is pretty useless.  Making ones that actually work requires client side functions which don't seem to be there.  Reimplementing them yourself is way harder than md5.

Comment: The link I provided lead to this [commit](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/commit/e169fa2c6a47d43c47b9b31ae82946edd5fc9d41). I don't do user management via npgsql so I don't know... but for sure it is possible to establish a connection using scram-sha-256